# how to distinguish css selector and css rules with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem to grab only the css properties and values(width:30px) from rules.

the main problem is :
- **what if there is a dot before css selector**

here is my regex formula:

```
(\s+)?([^\.])[a-z0-9-]+\s?:.[^;\n]*(?=;?)
```

And here is the string:

```
.icon-inverse{
    color:#fff
}

.icon-glass:before{
    content:"\f000";color:#asdf
```

The task is to select only the css properties and values in any format of css rules.(eg: property:value)

example

```
format 1
.div:hover{
width:200px;
height:100px
}

format 2
.div:hover{
width:200px; height : 100px;
}

format 2
.div:hover{width:200px; height : 100px}
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: screenshot of my code]

I wonder if this case is the limitation of RegExp ?

Comment: Have a look at [`/^(\s+)?[^.][a-z0-9-]+\s?:.[^;\n]*/m`](https://regex101.com/r/yV0oV5/1). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Why are you trying to parse CSS with regexps, instead of just looking at style objects? What do you mean by "a dot before the CSS property"? You say you are trying to grab values (width: 30px), but there is no such property in any of your rules. By the way, `(\s+)?` is exactly equivalent to `\s*`. Also, you do not need to escape the dot inside character sets.

Comment: I think that will not work, because I was tried to put [^.] but no  luck

Comment: @stribizhev this case is just accidentally happen while I was creating regex formula for css properties and values only. I am really curios about this case because I am still learning.

Comment: @torazaburo sorry my mistake, I mean a dot  before css selector

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try this:

[/{\s+([^;}\s]+)|;([^;}\s]+)/gim](https://regex101.com/r/jA8jU0/1)